# Creating a new DocumentSet instance using PnP library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, pnp

I have created a configured a SharePoint online Document Set along with it's custom welcome page to create a new document set by filling the required values for the mandatory columns.

There is a separate application that will need to create a new Document Set in this library.

I have looked at the PnP documentation and I can configure the Document Set content type, but I haven't been able to find how to specify the values for the required columns and create a new Document Set in this library.

How can I automate this process so that I can specify the properties and create the document set programmatically?

Comment: PnP Core? PnP PowerShell?

Comment: Hope this article may help: https://blog.meenavalli.in/post/spfx-creating-a-modern-document-set-using-pnpjs/